# Regex to extract minute and seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

How can I extract minutes and seconds from a `NSString`? Examples:

```
3'15" or 3' 15" (3 minutes 15 seconds)
28" (28 seconds)
2' (2 minutes)
50 (default is in seconds, 50 seconds)
```

and stores into two `NSInteger`s?

Comment: `(\d+')|(\d+[^'])` The second var will always be the seconds and the first will be the minutes

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely convinced that RegEx matching is the best way to read numbers out of a string, but here is a snippet that works:

```
NSString *str = @"12'34\"";

NSString *minutePattern = @"[[:digit:]]+'";
NSString *secondPattern = @"[[:digit:]]+\"?";

NSRange minuteRange = [str rangeOfString: minutePattern options: NSRegularExpressionSearch];

NSRange  secondStartRange;
NSString *minuteString = @"";
if ( minuteRange.location != NSNotFound) 
{
    minuteString = [str substringWithRange: minuteRange];
    NSUInteger secondStartPt = NSMaxRange(minuteRange);
    secondStartRange = NSMakeRange(secondStartPt, str.length - secondStartPt);
}
else {
    secondStartRange = NSMakeRange(0, str.length);
}

NSRange secondRange = [str rangeOfString: secondPattern 
                                 options: NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                   range: secondStartRange];

NSString *secondString = @"";
if ( secondRange.location != NSNotFound) 
{
    secondString = [str substringWithRange: secondRange];
}

NSInteger minutes = [minuteString integerValue];
NSInteger seconds = [secondString integerValue];

NSLog(@"Minutes: %d, seconds: %d", minutes, seconds);
```

Note that it will parse a string like `5'21` as 5 minutes 21 seconds, not sure if that is what you want, but that can be fixed with an extra test.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *data = @[@"3'15\"", @"3' 15\"", @"28\"", @"2'", @"50"];
NSString *pattern = @"(\\d++')|(\\d++(\"{0,1})$)";

NSRegularExpression *regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                          error:nil];
for (NSString *string in data) {
    NSInteger mi = 0;
    NSInteger ss = 0;

    NSArray *match = [regExp matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,string.length)];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in match) {

        NSString *value = [string substringWithRange:result.range];
        if ([value hasSuffix:@"'"]) {
            mi = [value integerValue];
        } else {
            ss = [value integerValue];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@ - %d %d",string,mi,ss);
}
```

Comment: It is always preverable to not only post code but some kind of explanation of it as well